# Compare Time Object In Java

Tags: java, date, calendar

How to compare to Two time object in Java.

Below code not Working for me.
if We compare to `mp.getStartTime()` is hh:mm:ss 08:00:00 and `selectedFacilityResource.getStartTime()`is hh:mm:ss 08:00:00 then it is returning -1.

```
import java.sql.Time;

class Facilityresources {
     @NotNull(message = " Start Time cannot be empty")
    private Time startTime;
    @NotNull(message = " End Time cannot be empty")
    private Time endTime;
//Getter Setters
}

if (tmp.getStartTime().compareTo(selectedFacilityResource.getStartTime()) > 0){

    }

   if (tmp.getStartTime().compareTo(selectedFacilityResource.getStartTime()) < 0){

    }

   if (tmp.getStartTime().compareTo(selectedFacilityResource.getStartTime()) == 0){

   }
```

[image]

Comment: what is `tmp.getStartTime()`? what is `selectedFacilityResource.getStartTime()`? Where do you compare `endTime`?

Comment: Well, the old `Date` object have `before` and `after` and also implements `Comparable`. Most of new date/time objects support similar concepts - so I guess the real question is - what's type of objects are you values

Comment: @jhamon Can you check Now

Comment: Have you tried to convert it to `LocalTime` which has convenient `isBefore()` and `isAfter()` for you. `sqlTime.toLocalTime();` to get LocalTime

Comment: No, I stil don't get why you say you try to compare startTime and endTime while you code compare only startTime from 2 different objects

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Sorry  I updated the question

Comment: Are there any milliseconds?

Comment: @jhamon Updated question

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Yes

Comment: what do you get by printing the 2 dates?

Comment: @jhamon Updated question

Comment: If you cannot provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which would clearly be best), could you at least print the *both* two values that you are comparing that give you the unexpected result?